# windows 8 tablet, touch screen and old applications

Tags: windows-8, mouse, touchscreen

Yes it's true! old foxpro 2.6 for windows applications are still alive and working great on windows 8 32-bit. However there is a problem on tablet pc: tapping does NOTHING in those old applications.
I expected that touch screen tap would be same as mouse left-click but it's not.
I've tried even older application (calc.exe from windows 3.1 !) and it works perfectly , tap on the screen works just like left-click on the mouse...??
Any suggestion please, solution maybe (other than telling me to use bluetooth mouse)?
Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: OK, no bluetooth mouse tip. How do you expect that current-day technology can be applied to software that was written over a decade ago? How about upgrading to a database of the 21st century? Access in its most recent three versions should work just fine with a touch screen. If you insist on using Foxpro 2.6, then use a desktop with XP. If you want to use a touch screen and show off in public, tapping away nonchalantly at crude, badly designed user interfaces,  bite the bullet and use a current database. If you want to use Win 8 in the quiet of your office, just use a flipping mouse.

Comment: thx for trying to help but it's not for showing off. it's for use in a warehouse and upgrading software to new platform would be too expensive , not in plans for next 2 years. it's shame there are so many emulators for old dos games tho, and no simple emulator that makes your touch screen behave like and old mouse

Comment: Now I've tried some other things: I installed teamviewer. My old application is on XP SP3 and I run it  (via teamviewer) using my windows 8 tablet. Everything works great. So some emulation happened , I use touchscreen on my tablet and it works just like a mouse on that XP machine. I thought there could be some kind of emulation like that , just locally, on my tablet..??
Any help would be apreciated